How to generate invoice pdf dynamically based on products
i want to generate an invoice pdf based on products count.
if there are products >= 5 then create a new page without affecting the content like cutting from in between or duplication.
here is my code,
  const downloadInvoice = (billData, termsData, BankDetailsData) => {
    // Create a complete invoice HTML with flexible layout
    const createFullInvoiceHTML = () => {
      const baseInvoice = InvoiceUI(billData, termsData, BankDetailsData);
      return baseInvoice;
    };

    // Create an invisible container
    const container = document.createElement('div');
    container.style.position = 'absolute';
    container.style.top = '-99999px';
    container.style.width = '210mm'; // A4 width
    container.innerHTML = createFullInvoiceHTML();
    document.body.appendChild(container);

    // Capture and generate PDF
    html2canvas(container, {
      scale: 3,
      logging: false,
      useCORS: true,
      allowTaint: true,
    })
      .then((canvas) => {
        const pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
        const imgWidth = 210;
        const pageHeight = 297;
        const imgHeight = canvas.height * (imgWidth / canvas.width);

        // Add pages systematically
        let position = 0;
        while (position < imgHeight) {
          // Add page if it's not the first iteration
          console.log('before 1.position 2.imgHeight', position, imgHeight);

          if (position > 0) {
            pdf.addPage();
          }

          // Calculate height for this page
          const remainingHeight = imgHeight - position;
          const pageImgHeight = Math.min(remainingHeight, pageHeight);

          // Add image portion
          pdf.addImage(
            canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 1),
            'PNG',
            0,
            -position,
            imgWidth,
            imgHeight,
            undefined,
            'FAST',
          );

          // Move to next page section
          position += pageHeight;
          console.log('before 1.position 2.imgHeight', position, imgHeight);
        }

        // Save PDF
        pdf.save(`Invoice_${billData?.invoice_no}.pdf`);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('PDF Generation Error:', error);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        document.body.removeChild(container);
        setDownloadInvoiceId(null);
      });
  };

and here is the HTML code for invoice --->
const InvoiceUI = (billData, termsData, BankDetailsData) => {
  const formattedDate = dayjs(billData?.date).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
  const items = billData?.bill_subs || [];
  const totalRate = items
    .reduce((acc, item) => acc + (parseFloat(item.rate) || 0), 0)
    .toFixed(2);
  const totalCgstAmount = items
    .reduce((acc, item) => acc + (item.cgst_amount || 0), 0)
    .toFixed(2);
  const totalSgstAmount = items
    .reduce((acc, item) => acc + (item.sgst_amount || 0), 0)
    .toFixed(2);
  const totalIgstAmount = items
    .reduce((acc, item) => acc + (item.igst_amount || 0), 0)
    .toFixed(2);
  const totalTaxAmount = items
    .reduce((acc, item) => acc + (item.total_tax_amount || 0), 0)
    .toFixed(2);
  const totalTaxAmountInWords = convertToWords(totalTaxAmount);

  const subtotal = items.reduce(
    (acc, item) => acc + item.rate * item.quantity,
    0,
  );

  return `
   <div style="padding: 10px; color:black; background-color: #fff; max-width: 900px; margin: 0px auto; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif; border-radius: 10px;">   
  <!-- Header -->
      <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: space-between; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">
 <img src=${FP002} alt="Fussion Pizza" style="width: 100%; height: 180px;" /> 
</div>
 <div style="flex: 1; text-align: center; border: 1px solid black;">
    <h2 style="margin: 5px;">TAX INVOICE</h2>
  </div>

 <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; width: 100%; margin: 0; border: 1px solid #000;">
  
  <!-- First Table: Company and Seller/Buyer Information -->
  <table style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; table-layout: fixed;">
  <tr>
    <!-- Left Column (60% Width) -->
    <td style="width: 60%; border-right: 1px solid #000; padding: 0px; vertical-align: top;">
      <strong style="padding: 8px">V B ENTERPRISE</strong>
     <p style="font-size: 14px; padding: 0px 8px; margin-top: 2px">
          ${billData?.seller_address || ''}<br />
        GSTIN/UIN: 24AATFV9382R1ZS<br />
        Contact: +91 80005 68007<br />
        E-mail: thefusionpizza1812@gmail.com
      </p>
       <hr style="border: none; border-top: 1px solid #000; width: 100%; margin: 0;" />
      <!-- Consignee (Seller) Section -->
      <div">
      <strong style="padding: 8px">Address:</strong>        
        <p style="color: #555; font-size: 14px;padding: 0px 8px; margin-top: 2px">
          ${billData?.buyer_address || ''} - ${
    billData?.buyer_pincode || ''
  } <br />
          GSTIN: ${billData?.buyer_gst_no || ''}
        </p>
      </div>
    <hr style="border: none; border-top: 1px solid #000; margin: 0; width: 100%;" />
      <!-- Buyer Section -->
      <div>
        <strong style="padding: 8px">Buyer:</strong>          
        <p style="color: #555; font-size: 14px;padding: 0px 8px; margin-top: 2px">
          ${billData?.buyer_name || ''}<br />
          ${billData?.buyer_contact_person_name || ''} <br />
          ${billData?.buyer_contact_person_number || ''}
        </p>
      </div>
    </td>
    
    <!-- Right Column (40% Width) -->
    <td style="width: 40%; padding: 0; vertical-align: top;">
      <table style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;">
        <tr>
          <td style="padding: 0; vertical-align: top; border-right: 1px #000;">
            <p style="margin: 0; padding: 10px 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #000; min-height: 20px;">
              <strong>Invoice No.:</strong>
              ${billData?.invoice_no || ''}
            </p>
            <p style="margin: 0;padding: 10px 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #000; min-height: 20px;">
              <strong>Delivery Note:</strong>
              ${billData?.delivery_note || ''}
            </p>
            <p style="margin: 0; padding: 10px 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #000; min-height: 20px;">
              <strong>Buyer's Order No.:</strong>
              ${billData?.buyer_order_no || ''}
            </p>
            <p style="margin: 0; padding: 10px 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #000; min-height: 20px;">
              <strong>Dispatch Doc No.:</strong>
              ${billData?.dispatch_doc_no || ''}
            </p>
             <p style="margin: 0; padding: 10px 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #000; min-height: 20px;">
              <strong>Dated:</strong>
              ${formattedDate || ''}
            </p>
            <p style="margin: 0; padding: 10px 5px;">
              <strong>Dispatched Through:</strong>
               ${billData?.dispatched_through || ''}
            </p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

<!-- Invoice Items Table -->
<table style="width: 100%; margin-top: 1px; border-collapse: collapse; font-size: 14px;">
  <thead style="background-color: #fff; border-bottom: 1px solid #333;">
    <tr>
      <th style="padding: 4 8px; border: 1px solid #333; background-color: #fff; text-align: center;">Sr No</th>
      <th style="padding: 4 8px; border: 1px solid #333; background-color: #fff; text-align: center;">Description of Goods and Services</th>
      <th style="padding: 5 10px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: center;">HSN/SAC</th>
      <th style="padding: 4 8px; border: 1px solid #333; background-color: #fff; text-align: center;">UOM</th>
      <th style="padding: 4 8px; border: 1px solid #333; background-color: #fff; text-align: center;">GST Rate</th>
      <th style="padding: 4 8px; border: 1px solid #333; background-color: #fff; text-align: center;">Qty</th>
      <th style="padding: 4 8px; border: 1px solid #333; background-color: #fff; text-align: center;">Rate</th>
      <th style="padding: 4 8px; border: 1px solid #333; background-color: #fff; text-align: center;">Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    ${
      items.length > 0
        ? items
            .map(
              (item, index) => `
      <tr>
        <td style="padding: 3 8px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: center;">${
          index + 1
        }</td>
        <td style="padding: 5px 8px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: left;"><strong>${
          item.product_name || ''
        }</strong></td>
        <td style="padding: 3 8px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: center;">${
          item.hsn_sac_code || ''
        }</td>
        <td style="padding: 3 8px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: center;">${
          item.uom_name || ''
        }</td>
        <td style="padding: 3 8px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: center;">${
          item.total_gst || ''
        }%</td>
        <td style="padding: 3 8px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: center;">${
          item.quantity || ''
        }</td>
        <td style="padding: 3 8px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: center;">${
          item.rate || ''
        }</td>
        <td style="padding: 3 8px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: right;">₹${
          (item.rate * item.quantity).toFixed(2) || '0.00'
        }</td>
      </tr>`,
            )
            .join('')
        : `<tr><td colspan="7" style="text-align: center; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #333;">No data available</td></tr>`
    }
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
  <tr>
      <td colspan="7" style="padding: 2 6px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: right; font-weight: bold;">Sub Total:</td>
      <td style="padding: 4 8px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: right; font-weight: bold;">₹${subtotal.toFixed(
        2,
      )}</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td colspan="7" style="padding: 2 6px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: right; font-weight: bold;">Tax Amount:</td>
      <td style="padding: 4 8px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: right; font-weight: bold;">₹${totalTaxAmount}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="7" style="padding: 2 6px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: right; font-weight: bold;">Transportation Charge:</td>
      <td style="padding: 4 8px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: right; font-weight: bold;">₹${
        billData?.trans_charge || '0.00'
      }</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td colspan="7" style="padding: 2 6px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: right; font-weight: bold;">Discount:</td>
      <td style="padding: 4 8px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: right; font-weight: bold;">₹${
        billData?.discount || '0.00'
      }</td>
    </tr>
      <td colspan="7" style="padding: 2 6px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: right; font-weight: bold;">Total:</td>
      <td style="padding: 4 8px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: right; font-weight: bold;">₹${
        billData?.total_amount || '0.00'
      }</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="8" style="padding: 4 8px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">
  Amount In Words: ${capitalizeWords(billData?.amount_in_words || 'Zero')} 
</td>
    </tr> 
  </tfoot>
</table>

    <!-- Tax Details Table -->
<table style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; font-size: 14px;">
  <thead style="background-color: #fff; border-bottom: 1px solid #333;">
    <tr>
      <th style="padding: 5 10px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: center;">HSN/SAC</th>
      <th style="padding: 5 10px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: center;">Taxable Value</th>
      <th style="padding: 5 10px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: center;">CGST Rate</th>
      <th style="padding: 5 10px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: center;">CGST Amount</th>
      <th style="padding: 5 10px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: center;">SGST Rate</th>
      <th style="padding: 5 10px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: center;">SGST Amount</th>
      <th style="padding: 5 10px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: center;">IGST Rate</th>
      <th style="padding: 5 10px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: center;">IGST Amount</th>
      <th style="padding: 5 10px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: center;">Total Tax Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    ${
      items.length > 0
        ? items
            .map(
              (item) => `
      <tr>
        <td style="padding: 3 8px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: center;">${
          item.hsn_sac_code || ''
        }</td>
        <td style="padding:3 8px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: right;">${
          (item.rate * item.quantity).toFixed(2) || '0.00'
        }</td>
        <td style="padding:3 8px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: right;">${
          `${item.cgst} %` || '-'
        }</td>
        <td style="padding:3 8px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: right;">${
          item.cgst_amount.toFixed(2) || '0.00'
        }</td>
        <td style="padding:3 8px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: right;">${
          `${item.sgst} %` || '-'
        }</td>
        <td style="padding:3 8px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: right;">${
          item.sgst_amount.toFixed(2) || '0.00'
        }</td>
        <td style="padding:3 8px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: right;">${
          `${item.igst} %` || '-'
        }</td>
        <td style="padding:3 8px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: right;">${
          item.igst_amount.toFixed(2) || '0.00'
        }</td>
        <td style="padding:3 8px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: right;">${
          item.total_tax_amount.toFixed(2) || '0.00'
        }</td>
      </tr>`,
            )
            .join('')
        : `<tr><td colspan="9" style="text-align: center; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #333;">No data available</td></tr>`
    }
  </tbody>
  <tfoot style="background-color: #fff;">
    <tr style="font-weight: bold;">
      <td style="padding:4px 8px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: left;">Total</td>
      <td style="padding:4 8px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: right;">${subtotal.toFixed(
        2,
      )}</td>
      <td style="padding:4 8px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: center;"></td>
      <td style="padding:4 8px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: right;">${totalCgstAmount}</td>
      <td style="padding:4 8px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: center;"></td>
      <td style="padding:4 8px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: right;">${totalSgstAmount}</td>
      <td style="padding:4 8px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: center;"></td>
      <td style="padding:4 8px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: right;">${totalIgstAmount}</td>
      <td style="padding:4 8px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: right;">${totalTaxAmount}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="9" style="padding: 5 8px; border: 1px solid #333; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">
  Tax Amount In Words: ${capitalizeWords(totalTaxAmountInWords || 'Zero')}
</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>


<!-- Terms and Bank Details -->
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; gap: 20px;">
  <!-- Terms and Conditions -->
  <div style="font-size: 14px; flex: 1 1 45%; padding: 0 10px; background-color: #fff; margin-top: 0; border-right: 2px solid #555;">
    <h4 style="color: #333; margin-bottom: 10px; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 600;">Terms and Conditions:</h4>
    <ul style="list-style: none; padding-left: 0px; color: #555; line-height: 1.2; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;">
      ${termsData
        ?.map(
          (term) =>
            `<li style="margin-bottom: 0; font-size: 12px; white-space: normal; position: relative; padding-left: 15px;">
               <span style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; content: '•'; font-size: 12px; line-height: 1.2; color: #555;">•</span>
               ${term?.terms_conditions}
             </li>`,
        )
        .join('')}
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- Bank Details -->
  <div style="font-size: 14px; flex: 1 1 45%; padding: 0 10px; background-color: #fff; border-radius: 8px; margin-top: 0;">
    <h4 style="color: #333; margin-bottom: 10px; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 600; text-align: left; padding: 0 0px"><strong>Bank Details:</strong></h4>
    <ul style="list-style: none; padding: 0 0px; color: #555; line-height: 1.6; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 10;">
      ${`
        <li><strong>Account Holder:</strong> ${
          BankDetailsData[0]?.account_holder_name || 'N/A'
        }</li>
        <li><strong>Branch Name:</strong> ${
          BankDetailsData[0]?.bank_name || 'N/A'
        }</li>
        <li><strong>Branch Name:</strong> ${
          BankDetailsData[0]?.branch_name || 'N/A'
        }</li>
        <li><strong>Account Type:</strong> ${
          BankDetailsData[0]?.account_type || 'N/A'
        }</li>
        <li><strong>Account Number:</strong> ${
          BankDetailsData[0]?.account_number || 'N/A'
        }</li>
        <li><strong>IFSC Code:</strong> ${
          BankDetailsData[0]?.ifsc_code || 'N/A'
        }</li>
        <li><strong>UPI ID:</strong> ${BankDetailsData[0]?.upi_id || 'N/A'}</li>
      `}
    </ul>
    <!-- Horizontal line styled to align with the border -->
    <hr style="border: none; border-top: 2px solid #555; width: calc(100% + 20px); margin: 0 -32px;" />
    <br />
    <span style="float: right; font-size: 12px; color: #555; margin-right: 12px;">Authorised Signatory</span>
  </div>
</div>

 <div style="width: 100%; margin-top:20px; background-color: #004d00; color: #ffffff; padding: 15px; text-align: center; font-size: 12px; border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;">
  <!-- Contact Information -->
  <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; gap: 20px;">
    <!-- Phone -->
    <div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
      <img src=${phone} alt="Phone Icon" style="margin-right: 5px; height: 20px; width: 20px">
      <span>+91 80005 68007 | +91 95378 86454</span>
    </div>
    <!-- Email -->
    <div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
      <img src=${email} alt="Email Icon" style="margin-right: 5px; height: 20px; width: 20px">
      <span>thefusionpizza1812@gmail.com</span>
    </div>
    <!-- Address -->
    <div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
      <img src=${website} alt="Address Icon" style="margin-right: 5px; height: 20px; width: 20px">
      <span>www.thefusionpizza.in | www.bigburger.co.in</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
  `;
};

The problem with above code is that it cuts the invoice from in between when new page is added. here is the image --->
enter image description here
if there is any way to add new page without cutting the content.
